# Tags that should never be the only ones on a question

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta-tags

It seems to me that there are some tags that if they are the only ones on a post (or even if they are mentioned at all) pretty much make the question off topic. Perhaps these tags should have a warning similar to that appearing on the [blackberry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blackberry) or they should be removed or something else.

Some examples are: [legal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/legal),[e-commerce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce),[illegal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/illegal),[shopping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shopping) (though there are some questions that are tagged shopping that are not closed, I think many of them should be) [amazon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon), [amazon-web-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services),[automotive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/automotive),[bing-maps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bing-maps)[blog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blog), [blogger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogger) ,[blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging), [bloglines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bloglines), [blogspot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogspot), [box](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/box), [c](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c#](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [cellular](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cellular), [cellular-internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cellular-internet), [classified](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/classified), [cloud-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage), [online-backup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/online-backup), [copyright](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copyright), [culture](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/culture),[dropout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropout), [ebay](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ebay),[economics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/economics), [facebook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/facebook).

Would it be possible for a mod or someone else to either remove these tags, or make it clear somehow that they are used in a totally different way than they are generally used? For example, if legal is talking about a filename, then that is fine, but that is generally not the way that it is used. While I could submit a wiki tag edit, it would then just be confusing as it would have nothing to do with the question.

There are also tags that just don't say anything (meta tags?).
Some examples are: [advice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/advice),[angry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/angry), [attack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/attack), [complete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/complete), [create](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/create), [custom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/custom), [daily](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/daily), [dead](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dead),  [digital](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/digital), [dreaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dreaming), [exam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exam), [exam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exam), [exists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exists), [express](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/express) (least the way it is used now, i.e. inconsistently) [eye](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eye), [fail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fail), [failed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failed), [failing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failing), [family](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/family), [career](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/career),[cost](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cost), [cost-benefit](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cost-benefit), [cheap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cheap), [eula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eula),[budget](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/budget).

These tags should be removed I think.

**EDIT 1:** I tried to put the following text in the wiki summary of the tags in my first group:

> Please make sure that if you are using this tag, your question conforms to the FAQ, namely that it is about computer hardware or software.

After getting the first two accepted, the rest were rejected (I assume as I can no longer submit edits for seven days).

Comment: Keep in mind, you have the ability to suggest tag wiki edits. For the first batch you mention, you can go through and edit the tag wikis to include a warning that those questions are typically off topic. We'll look through them and see if any should be banned or widely removed. We can take a look at the second batch of tags and consider some of them for blacklisting.

Comment: I could but some of them don't seem worth saving (like [tag:cost] for example). It is in the first group because it tells me something, but I can't think of legitimate use for the tag.

Comment: if you think the tag shouldn't exist, then put it in your list for burnination.

Comment: @nhinkle, I can no longer edit tag wikis for a week, see edit.

Comment: For your list of tags that don't say anything, I'd probably nuke all of them except for "attack", "eula".

Comment: How can EULA be on topic?

Comment: Well, definitely not by itself. But it might be for questions like "If I have a CD of this software, can I install it on another computer?", et cetera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I burninated:

> [advice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/advice),[angry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/angry), [attack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/attack), [complete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/complete), [create](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/create), [custom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/custom), [daily](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/daily), [dead](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dead),  [digital](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/digital), [dreaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dreaming), [exam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exam), [exam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exam), [exists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exists), [express](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/express) (least the way it is used now, i.e. inconsistently) [eye](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eye), [fail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fail), [failed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failed), [failing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failing), [family](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/family), [career](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/career),[cost](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cost), [cost-benefit](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cost-benefit), [cheap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cheap), [eula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eula),[budget](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/budget).

(note that exam was listed twice here.. did you mean another tag?)

[image: tags burninated]

Comment: Can you add the burninations to the blocked tags list, too?

Comment: we generally don't do that unless they are recurring problems, otherwise you clutter the blacklist with a lot of not-so-useful entries

Comment: Seems reasonable. Thanks for the info.