# Appeal tag wiki ban?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Is it possible for me to appeal the ban that I have on editing tag wikis? The reason I got the ban is for trying to add the following text to the tag wikis of some tags:

> Please make sure that if you are using this tag, your question conforms to the FAQ, namely that it is about computer hardware or software.

I was doing this per the instruction of @nhinkle (see [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3202/tags-that-should-never-be-the-only-ones-on-a-question) for more detail, not there there is much).

I am a user in good standing, and the reason that I was banned is invalid (or so I think).

Is there a way for me to get the ban removed?

Comment: Include the warning, but not make it the whole excerpt

Comment: @Random I can't do that now, I can't even click on edit without getting "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days."

Comment: Wait seven days

Comment: So there is no way to appeal this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait the seven (7) days before trying again.

The timeout is to slow down users suggesting edits that may not be up to scratch and need of some refinement.

In your tag wiki excerpts, while a suggested use of the tag is fine to include, making it the entirety wasn't the intention.

A lesson learnt for next time: When submitting suggested edits, don't flood the queue with the same type of copy otherwise you'll be pushed back and you don't give yourself a chance to learn what's good, bad or needs improvement.

Comment: I understand that now. I don;t think it merits a ban though. It was an honest mistake.

Comment: It's better next time to not suggesting all the same edit copy at the same time so you know what not to do