# Drop kick [dropout]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Is [dropout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropout) useful?

A [long time ago](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3202/213131) it was identified as a tag that should never be the only tag on a question...a good sign it's a meta tag.

There are only 4 [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropout) tagged as such so I get it's not a hot mess. But I like SU best when it's tidy...

Comment: tag deleted from those four questions...

Comment: But what if OP can prove the issue is directly related to the fact the person with the problem has the problem because they quit school?

Comment: @music2myear Then put it in the question, not in the tags. Not everything needs it's own tag.

Comment: It was a joke. If the reason for the problem is that they quit school it is not a technical issue and therefore not on-topic here at all.

Comment: These comments are off-topic. I tried creating a `[joke]` tag so they'd have a place in the discussion but it was rejected with the error *Can't assign work to a null pointer*. Rats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken care of by @DavidPostill as per his comment:

> tag deleted from those four questions...